# Excel VBA Date Time Add Automatically

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have the following value on Excel Sheet.

```
A1 = 2018-01-01 00:00:00
A2 = 2018-01-07 23:59:59
```

I want to change the values automatically, let say everyday at `1AM`.
The changes should be like:
from `A1 = 2018-01-01 00:00:00` to `A1 = 2018-01-08 00:00:00` is the next day after `A2` value and from `A2` is plus 7 days from `A1`. So, it should be `A2 = 2018-01-15 23:59:59`.

Is it possible to do that? Please advice.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, you can use the [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateadd-function) function. For example:

```
NewDate = DateAdd("d", 7, "2018-01-01 00:00:00")
```

To run it every 1AM, put it in a `Sub` procedure (e.g. my_Procedure) and use the [Application.OnTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel) method to schedule it:

```
Application.OnTime TimeValue("1:00:00"), "my_Procedure", , False
```

Comment: How can I add 1 second from `A2` value?

Comment: Hi Tom, I got the answer... `DateAdd("s", 1, Sheet1.Range("A2"))`

Comment: Hi Tom, how can I run it every 1AM ?

Comment: what do you meant with 'procedure' @Tom?

Comment: [`Sub` procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/sub-procedures)